# Error connecting to openshift server with using IDE

Tags: jboss-tools, openshift-origin

I've installed OpenShift v3 tools v.3.0.0.Beta2 from http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/mars/ 
I'm using Eclipse Java Mars IDE on Ubuntu 14.04 with Java 8.

I'm trying to connect to server using the connection wizard. I've used openshift.redhat.com as server and I've selected the basic auth protocol

but I'm getting the following error:

```
com.openshift.restclient.OpenShiftException: Exception getting the resource
at com.openshift.internal.restclient.DefaultClient.handleHttpClientException(DefaultClient.java:396)
at com.openshift.internal.restclient.DefaultClient.get(DefaultClient.java:241)
at com.openshift.internal.restclient.DefaultClient.getCurrentUser(DefaultClient.java:402)
at com.openshift.internal.restclient.authorization.AuthorizationClient.getContext(AuthorizationClient.java:89)
at com.openshift.internal.restclient.DefaultClient.getContext(DefaultClient.java:407)
at org.jboss.tools.openshift.core.connection.Connection.authorize(Connection.java:210)
at org.jboss.tools.openshift.core.connection.Connection.connect(Connection.java:200)
at org.jboss.tools.openshift.internal.common.ui.connection.ConnectionWizardPageModel.connect(ConnectionWizardPageModel.java:263)
at org.jboss.tools.openshift.internal.common.ui.connection.ConnectionWizardPage$ConnectJob.doRun(ConnectionWizardPage.java:335)
at org.jboss.tools.openshift.internal.common.core.job.AbstractDelegatingMonitorJob.run(AbstractDelegatingMonitorJob.java:36)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: com.openshift.internal.restclient.http.NotFoundException:
404 Not found
```

Am I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If openshift.redhat.com is the server that you're trying to connect to while having "OpenShift v3" set in server type, then the reason is quite simple: openshift.redhat.com is not a v3 server (yet), it's for now a v2 only server. If you currently want to try out OpenShift v3 you'll have to download, install and run it on your own. You can find the instructions here: http://www.openshift.org//

Comment: Ah,ok. I installed the OpenShift v3 tools plugin from same server and it worked well.